# How can I clear only one worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear the contents of worksheet one after the following macro. I have tried using Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents, but it seems to clear both sheets. I have a feeling it has to do with the Do...Until loop I have, despite putting the clear line right after Loop. This is the first macro I have written and am still learning hence all the comments.

```
Sub LookUpTable()

'Declare Variables'

Dim rngB As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim iCountComma
Dim VarArr As Variant
Dim i As Long

'Separate Cell C2 into Column C by Comma'

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rngB = sh.Range("C2")
For Each Rng In rngB
    If InStr(Rng, ",") > 0 Then
    iCountComma = Len(Rng) - Len(Replace(Rng, ",", ""))
    VarArr = Split(Rng, ",")
    For i = 0 To iCountComma
        Rng.Offset(i) = Trim(VarArr(i))
    Next
End If
Next

'I Don't really know what these do'

Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'Declare Variables'

Dim BedPre As String
Dim BedSuf As String
Dim HISPre As String
Dim HISSuf As String
Dim ID As String
Dim Bed As String
Dim HIS As String
Dim NextRow As Long

'Assign cell values to variables'

BedPre = Range("A2").Value
BedSuf = Range("B2").Value
HISPre = Range("D2").Value
HISSuf = Range("E2").Value
ID = Range("F2").Value

'Select Cell C2'

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("C2").Select

'Loop until empty value in Column C'

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

'Find last empty cell in sheet 2'

NextRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'Concantenate cells and append Sheet 2'

Bed = BedPre & ActiveCell & BedSuf
HIS = HISPre & ActiveCell & HISSuf
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NextRow, 1) = Bed
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NextRow, 2) = HIS
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NextRow, 3) = ID
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: So you have a second sheet? What is the value in C2?

Comment: This script is used to build tables for mapping beds. C2 is a list of all the rooms separated by comma. The top piece of script lists the beds down column C. On the second page the table is built with many of the data pieces concatenated to reflect the code for the device and the code for the room followed by the path of data flow.

Comment: Unless you are overwriting the contents of Sheet2 with empty strings in the Do Loop, I don't see anything else that could clear Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see data clear both sheets. 
you can use this code

```html
Sub LookUpTable()

'Declare Variables'

Dim Rng As Range
Dim VarArr As Variant
Dim i As Long

Dim BedPre As String
Dim BedSuf As String
Dim HISPre As String
Dim HISSuf As String
Dim ID As String
Dim Bed As String
Dim HIS As String
Dim NextRow As Long

'Assign cell values to variables'
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    BedPre = Range("A2").Value
    BedSuf = Range("B2").Value
    HISPre = Range("D2").Value
    HISSuf = Range("E2").Value
    ID = Range("F2").Value
    Set Rng = .Range("C2")
End With
NextRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
If InStr(Rng, ",") > 0 Then
    VarArr = Split(Rng, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(VarArr)
        Bed = BedPre & Trim(VarArr(i)) & BedSuf
        HIS = HISPre & Trim(VarArr(i)) & HISSuf
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NextRow, 1) = Bed
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NextRow, 2) = HIS
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(NextRow, 3) = ID
    Next
End If
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:F2").ClearContents
End Sub
```